# Focus input field with JQuery without selecting current value text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

```
$("#myinputfield").focus();
```

Doing that on an input field with it's value already set causes the current value to be selected. How can I focus the field without selecting the text?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If you tab to a field it is also selected. This is standard user behavior. Where do you expect the caret to be? (Start of the text? End of the text?)

Comment: @Phrogz it could behave the same way textareas do now (contents are not selected when tabbing into one). It's not the same across browsers but as long as it's consistent..

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I've searched around a bit and kinda found out that you should re-set your value into the desired field after it is focussed on.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371430/jquery-focus-is-highlighting-all-pre-filled-text

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in chrome when the field is tabbed into.

Answer (score 26):

How about something like this where you set the value of the input field to itself after focusing it?

```
$("#myinputfield").focus().val($("#myinputfield").val());
```

Answer (score 7):

Other answers suggest setting the value of the input field to itself after focusing it. If in Firefox, the cursor appears at the start of the input and you want it at the end, then a slight modification is required. You will have to set the value as empty first and then set it to the previous value.

```
var value = $("#myinputfield").val();
$("#myinputfield").focus().val('').val(value);
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this?

```
var txt = $("#myinputfield").val();
$("#myinputfield").focus();
$("#myinputfield").val( txt );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function focusField(id){
    var inputField = document.getElementById(id);
    if (inputField != null && inputField.value.length != 0){
        if (inputField.createTextRange){
            var FieldRange = inputField.createTextRange();
            FieldRange.moveStart('character',inputField.value.length);
            FieldRange.collapse();
            FieldRange.select();
        }else if (inputField.selectionStart || inputField.selectionStart == '0') {
            var elemLen = inputField.value.length;
            inputField.selectionStart = elemLen;
            inputField.selectionEnd = elemLen;
            inputField.focus();
        }
    }else{
        inputField.focus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $field = $("#formloginusername"),
        oldVal = $field.val();
    $field.focus().val('').val(oldVal);
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/X7Y8S/

i took the code & demo from ahren's answer in other topic, i think it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works very well for me:

```
$("#myinputfield").focus(function (event) {
  var value = $("#myinputfield").val();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#myinputfield").val(value);
  },10);
});
```