# In Chrome, focusing an HTML text input field selects the contents. How to unselect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, forms, html-input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Focus input field with JQuery without selecting current value text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756926/focus-input-field-with-jquery-without-selecting-current-value-text)

Using the following code to focus the first field in the form:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form input:visible:enabled:first").focus();        
});
```

Why does it select the text in the field? How to focus the input without selecting the text?

Working in Ruby on Rails. Tested on Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("form input:visible:enabled:first").focus().val('Yeah');        
});​
```

If you dunno what the value is going to be, you can do:

```
var $firstInput = $("form input:visible:enabled:first")
$firstInput.focus().val($firstInput.val());
```

I'm going to try to find a better solution, though.