# Using Javascript .focus() highlights text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form like so:

```
<form action='word.php' name = 'searchbox'>
<input type='text' name='word' id = 'searchbox' value = 'default'>
</form>
```

In my body I have:

```
<body onLoad="searchbox.word.focus()">
```

You can see the fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/WEZ7S/

What I'm trying to achieve is just have a blinking cursor at the end of "default", but instead the whole word gets selected instead.

Surprisingly Google hasn't been able to find any solutions. How would I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery .focus() is highlighting all pre-filled text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371430/jquery-focus-is-highlighting-all-pre-filled-text)

Comment: This is the default behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a previously answered question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13371452/1238887

Here's a nifty little trick:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $field = $("#searchbox"),
        oldVal = $field.val();
    $field.focus().val('').val(oldVal);
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/X7Y8S/

Comment: @mohabitar - yes it does, I'm on chrome. It's probably because it's a jQuery solution and you were just asking about javascript. See blender's answer for a pure JS workaround.

Comment: Ok just got it to work in my code on all browsers after fiddling around, thanks!

Comment: Great trick... However, when I use this, it also forces `autofocus` on that field. In my case, I would need to `autofocus` another field, then, for example, if tab were pressed to go to field in question, then the behavior in question would occur...

Answer (score 3):

You can get around this by resetting the `.value` property of the element:

```
searchbox.word.focus();
searchbox.word.value = searchbox.word.value;
```

There are also less hacky solutions: [Use JavaScript to place cursor at end of text in text input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element)

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WEZ7S/1/**

Comment: Awesome, this worked in Safari and Chrome but not Firefox. Any way around that?

Comment: @mohabitar: Look at the long answer in the question that I linked to. It's a jQuery plugin, so you'll need jQuery to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`setSelectionRange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Input.setSelectionRange) (Chrm, FF):

```
var len = searchbox.word.length;

searchbox.word.focus();
searchbox.word.setSelectionRange(len, len);
```